# What insect is this, is it a bed bug?

Tags: entomology

I woke up a week ago with bites all over my arms and legs, and some in a straight line.

We brought round a beg bug expert but he could not find anything in the room.

However, this morning we found this creature, and binned it.

Can anyone identify what it is?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Welcome youngcouple10. Can you [edit] to tell us whereabouts in the world you live.  It's very difficult to say from the picture as it's low definition and from an odd angle. Can you supply a clearer picture, a close-up from directly above? (If you can't, my guess is that *if* it had a pointy tail we can't see at this angle, it's a ladybird larva, 3rd or 4th instar.)